# How do you prevent videos from being recorded on the browser by the 'CoCoCut'?

Tags: video, video-recording

How do you prevent videos from being recorded on the browser by the 'CoCoCut'?

Comment: What makes you think it's possible to stop video downloading by CoCoCut? Did you **research** if any website can stop it, and also checked their source to see how they did it?

Answer (score 0):

it's simple: you can't. Not unless you coded something that detects if someone has cococut, and refuses to play the video entirely if they have it. that's the only way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).